# Best .Net pdf library to generate data tables

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, pdf, pdf-generation

I am looking around for a good free .Net pdf library, in particular to generate data in tables easily and flexibly. I have seen [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/) but this requires a license from what I've read. There is also [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/MainPage.ashx) which looks promising using MigraDoc for table generation. Is there anything else anyone recommends?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the data come from ? If it comes from a database then Reporting Services is way preferable over handcrafting documents. If it doesn't come from a database, build one to store your data and see above. EDIT: more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329672/sql-server-compact-edition-and-reporting-is-ssrs-an-option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ItextSharp 4 released under the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) 
by using version 4 or earlier you can use without having to buy a license.

For version 4 heres the link, download the code and in bin folder you will get ITextsharp old version dll
**[itextsharp 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001758/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030911-1.aspx)**

**[Here the updated Itextsharp dll](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)**

Or you can also use client side PDF generation using **[Jspdf](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf)**

Comment: Unfortunately the link only provides version 5 of the libraries which I imagine need a license?

Comment: Heres the link, download the code and in bin folder you will get ITextsharp old version dll refer http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030911-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much! I've decided to plump for iTextSharp (the LGPL version 4) - seems very well supported and quite straightforward to use.

Comment: @Jeb: happy coding,  usefull tutorial link refer http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/80/Create-PDFs-in-ASP.NET-getting-started-with-iTextSharp