# SQL Server Compact 4.0 SSRS 2014

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to use a SQL Server Compact database as a data source for SSRS which was installed with SQL Server 2014.

I followed the answer provided here.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e827cb19-82ec-49c6-a274-addb5b382ee3/can-ssrs-2008-use-sql-server-compact-35-as-datasource?forum=sqlreportingservices

I am able to see SQL Server Compact as an option for Data Sources.

SQL Server Compact 4.0 is installed. However, when trying to use the data source to create a data set, I get this error:

[image: DataExtension Sql Compact Error]

The linked to post above is in reference to SSRS 2008. Is this possible with more current versions of SSRS?

Comment: did you tried a simplest select query to see if you are facing same issue?

Comment: Are you able to query the database directly.. say using SSMS or something similar for example?

Comment: @ViKiNG yes. Same error.

Comment: @Harry - yes.  Querying database using CompactView

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the same credentials in SSRS as you are in CompactView. How are you creating your dataset? Direct query or using query designer?

Comment: might want to check this out too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329672/sql-server-compact-edition-and-reporting-is-ssrs-an-option

Comment: @Harry - tried both direct query and using query designer.  The db is local on my machine.  I've tried various credential options but I don't need to enter credentials to access the db on my machine.  I've seen that post.  I might try that if I learn that SSRS is not an option.